# Relative file path not working on S3 hosted static website with cloudfront

Tags: html, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have the following file structure

------------------------------------

index.html

/bundle

- styles.css

/broker

- submit.html

------------------------------------

I wish to be using the same css import path of

```
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/bundle/styles.css' />
```

so it would work for both index.html and submit.html

------------------------------------

However I've only been able to resolve this by using absolute file paths

so in index.html

```
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='./bundle/styles.css' />
```

and in submit.html

```
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='../bundle/styles.css' />
```

But as far as I'm aware, I should be able to use relative pathing? This has to be something super simple and i'm missing something right? I am also using cloudfront before the s3 bucket if that also can lead to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same setup as you had with Cloudfront in front of S3 bucket and S3 has static website content. I can use path you want to use without any issue. Also I can see cloudfront making separate request to download the stylesheet [image]

As you can see in attached image first request for index.html and second is for styles.css. Also see attached index.html where I am using path.[image]
One thing you want to check is your cloudfront path behaviour, I got it default(*) going to S3 bucket and nothing else, also check the S3 directory structure .